# select for rows that don't have a string

Tags: r, filter

I have a df of lot #'s with all of the data associated with them.  Some of that data is experimental.  Those lot #'s start with X.  For example, X42A7299, where any normal lot would be 42A7299.  I want to exclude those rows.  The DF is called all_cls4.  Here is the code I have tried:

```
all_cls4new<- all_cls4 %>% filter(!str_detect(Lot_#, ^X))
```

this returns a +
I also get this result with filter and !grep.  What am I missing?

Comment: Put your pattern in quotes, '^X', you don't need `!`, `str_detect(Lot_#, '^X', negate = TRUE)`, this imagining Lot_# is column name in all_cls4 (df), though you might put some data `dput(head(als4, n = 6))` and copy contents of `structure(...)` above.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

x <- tribble(
  ~lot,        ~other_data,
  "X42A7299",   45,
  "42A7299",    100
)

x %>% 
  filter(!(str_detect(lot, '^X')))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   lot     other_data
#>   <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 42A7299        100
```

Also, be careful with a symbol in your column name (e.g. Lot_#). I would rename it to a "clean" name (e.g. snakecase). `janitor::clean_names()` is useful for this. If you use it as is, you will have to wrap in backticks:

```r
x %>% 
  filter(!(str_detect(`Lot_#`, '^X')))
```

Comment: Worked, thanks for the tips, including the one for naming.